# Unit testing $httpBackend angular no response defined

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I'm struggling in my first test so please bear with me.
I want to test a function that make a http post:

```
$scope.formData= 'client=' + $scope.client_selected + '&version=' + $scope.version_selected + '&modules=' + $scope.client.modules;
        var response = $http.post('http://localhost:8080/mavenproject8/lol/form', $scope.formData);
        response.success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.validity = true;
            $scope.status = "true";
        });
        response.error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.status = "false";
            alert("Exception details: " + JSON.stringify({data: data}));
```

and my test looks like this:

```
...
beforeEach(inject(function ($injector) {
    // Set up the mock http service responses
    $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
    $httpBackend.when('POST', 'http://localhost:8080/mavenproject8/lol/form', data)
            .respond([200, {success: true, errors: [{}]}]);
```

and this is the `it` block:

```
it('should succeed when everything is correct', function () {
    $rootScope.client.modules=["360"];
    $rootScope.version_selected="2.4.0"
    $rootScope.client_selected="NSM";
    $rootScope.formData='client=' + $rootScope.client_selected + '&version=' + $rootScope.version_selected + '&modules=' + $rootScope.client.modules;
    $httpBackend.expectPOST('http://localhost:8080/mavenproject8/lol/form',$rootScope.formData);
    $rootScope.myFunc();
    expect($rootScope.validity).toBe(true);
});
```

But this test doesn't pass, with the error:

```
Error: No response defined !
```

I feel like I'm so close but I can't make it work. I would be grateful if you could help me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, your expected post request doesn't specify a response, that's why you see that error, so all what you have to do is:

```
$httpBackend.expectPOST('http://localhost:8080/mavenproject8/lol/form').respond(200,{});
//don't forget to make the flush after the function call.!!
$rootScope.myFunc();
$httpBackend.flush();
```

( you can dont need the $httpBackend.whenPost because that's useful when you want to create a back end definition, and  specify the response( `get` case for example) so you can remove it, and your test will still pass.)